# Can a value converter execute on different thread?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, asynchronous, ivalueconverter

If my Binding.IsAsync = true, then why doesn't my ValueConverter execute on the same  "supposingly non-UI" thread?

Is there **any** way to make it execute on that thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for `IsAsync` suggests that only your property accessors will be called asynchronously. No mention of converters is made that I can find. I'm not entirely sure whether this is because it's technically not possible to call the converter on the BG thread, or perhaps it was overlooked. It seems to me that it *should* be possible.

As a workaround, can you move any heavy logic being performed by your converter into the property, or perhaps into a separate property altogether?

Comment: +1 for the info. Yep that is a work around, but I was hoping probably some threading based `Attribute` can make it asynchronous on its own. :)